# Project Task save button not working in odoo

Tags: odoo-10

When I go to created task and edit fields, then press the save button but the page not refreshing or save the edited one.but when refreshing the changes save and appear. How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache or testing with a different browser?

Comment: @Ridma please compile fresh copy of stable version of odoo and always test in private browser so you never face any problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to check whether there is a return in write method. If return method not in the write method the page not refresh.